# Anaconda: Draco:1045 Getting Access Denied for user 'username''@'local host'

Tags: python, mysql, anaconda

Getting **Access denied** error while running python script for draco in Anaconda Prompt. I ran draco.py script.

Please suggest how to resolve. Thanks!

Comment: This error occurs because you have not mentioned proper login credentials of your DB.. So when the draco script tries to connect your DB it will raise this error!

Comment: Thanks for your reply,I have mentioned login credential in config.cfg file and also created tunnel setting through putty.